# jenkins powershell msiexec unable to install the .msi package on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, jenkins, windows-installer

I am trying to install a msi package via jenkins on a remote computer. Both the msi file and the powershell script are on the remote machine. 
From jenkins (which is another machine), using a powershell plugin trying to use the command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:client -ScriptBlock { param($mach,$u,$p) c:\install\scripts\Install_msi.ps1 -database $mach -username $u -password $p } -Credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP -Args $env:database,$env:username,$env:password
```

This is a company created application, packaged in  an msi format. This msi package has an application and also launches a c++ `dbsetup.exe` which installs the databases.

When I run the powershell script `install_msi.ps1` on a powershell command window as administrator directly on the remote machine, it installs the application including the dbsetup.exe launched and installs the databases.

The problem is when I try to do the same thing from jenkins, it installs only the application part but doesn't run `dbsetup.exe` and databases aren't installed. 
However I can see from the task manager that `dbsetup.exe` is launched and status showing as running but none of the databases are installed.

Using Powershell v4, Windows Server 2012 standard R2. Jenkins v1.612

Jenkins server is on one domain and remote machine is on another domain.

I am out of ideas. Any suggestions how to resolve this issue would be great.